# How do see source code in jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have httpmime-4.1.2.jar this jar file , I want to see the source for the Multipartentity class in eclipse. How do i see this in eclipse?

Comment: You need to download the source archive and tell Eclipse about it. A normal jar does not contain sources.

Comment: Do you have the source code as a jar or zip file or a directory with you? If yes, I can tell you how to attach it using Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

Download the source of this library and use `attach  source` in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the source in eclipse. It will need to be decompiled.
You can do in eclipse, see [JD-Eclipse](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse)

> JD-Eclipse is a plug-in for the Eclipse platform. It allows you to display all the Java sources during your debugging process, even if you do not have them all.
>
> JD-Eclipse is free for non-commercial use. This means that JD-Eclipse shall not be included or embedded into commercial software products. Nevertheless, this project may be freely used for personal needs in a commercial or non-commercial environments.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see it, you need to download source code separately. jar file does not contain source code, only bytecode. You must download the source and then use attach source in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jd-gui](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) to see the Java source codes of “.class” files.